# Set-AZVMOperatingSystem fails to set TimeZone when creating VM from Image

Tags: azure, timezone, azure-virtual-machine

I am creating a VM in Azure from a custom Image (originated from an official Azure Image, then custom software applied and sysprepped)

When Sysprepping, we have not used an unattend.xml

I create the VM using the following code:

```
$Vm = New-AZVMConfig -VMName $Server.BaseVMName `
                     -VMSize 'Standard_D2s_v3' `
                     -Tags @{Enviroment = 'Testers'}

$Vm = Set-AZVMSourceImage -VM $Vm `
                          -Id $Image.Id

$Vm = Set-AZVMOSDisk -VM $Vm `
                     -Name $Server.BaseDiskName `
                     -StorageAccountType Standard_LRS `
                     -DiskSizeInGB '128' `
                     -CreateOption FromImage `
                     -Caching ReadWrite

$Vm = Set-AZVMOperatingSystem -VM $Vm `
                              -Windows `
                              -ComputerName $Server.BaseVMName `
                              -Credential $Cred `
                              -ProvisionVMAgent `
                              -TimeZone 'Canada Central Standard Time'

$Vm = Add-AZVMNetworkInterface -VM $Vm `
                               -Id $nic.Id

$Vm = Set-AZVMBootDiagnostics -VM $Vm `
                              -Enable `
                              -ResourceGroupName $Server.BaseVMRsg `
                              -StorageAccountName $Server.BaseVMName.ToLower()

$Vm = New-AZVM -VM $Vm `
               -ResourceGroupName $Server.BaseVMRsg `
               -Location 'West Europe' `
               -DisableBginfoExtension `
```

However once the VM is created, the time zone is still UTC, not Canada Central Standard Time.

If I run the command:

```
(Get-AzVm -ResourceGroupName my_test_rsg -Name TestVM).OSProfile.WindowsConfiguration
```

it shows that it has accepted the TimeZone I put in:

```
ProvisionVMAgent          : True
EnableAutomaticUpdates    : False
TimeZone                  : Canada Central Standard Time
AdditionalUnattendContent : 
WinRM                     :
```

How can I investigate and understand why it is not setting the Time Zone as expected?

Comment: I'm confused by your statement `...the time zone is still UTC, not GMT.`  You're setting the time zone for Canada's Saskatchewan province, which is UTC-6 without daylight saving time. What are you looking at when you say "still UTC not GMT"?  What are you expecting to see?

Comment: Sorry I have corrected the question.

Comment: Thanks.  So, where are you checking this in the VM? Does `tzutil.exe /g` show it?  Also, this is probably getting off-topic for Stack Overflow, and might better fit on Server Fault.  But let's continue for now. :)

Comment: I am checking the VM by RDP'in into it, and can see in the Date and Time settings, that it is still set to UTC. tzutil.exe /g shows UTC. I can move the question tomorrow sorry.

Comment: Oh, no problem.  Yeah, it sounds like the setting is being ignored even though you are setting it correctly.  You may be able to get help with this through Azure support.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request

Answer (score 0):

I would check the following that has the same question

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/394392eb-21a4-4f67-8b58-0531ed445c17/how-to-set-timezone-on-windows-azure-virtual-machines

It also mentions how changing the time zone of a VM is not recommended. Instead you should develop your applications around the default UTC time